# What's type Object function arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments

I run below code,why is this result

```
function show(a,b) {
    arguments[0] = 10;
    arguments[1] = 20;
    console.log(a,b);
}
show();//undefined undefined
show(2);//10 undefined
```

look this code,why? what's different [10] [0:10]? this code run in browser

```
function show(a) {
    console.log(arguments);
    arguments[0] = 10;
    console.log(arguments)
    console.log(a);
}
show();//[] [0: 10] undefined
show(2);//[2] [10] 10
```

Comment: What languages? JavaScript? "Arguments" isn't a useful tag.

Comment: Yes,It's JavaScript

Comment: So what is your question?

Comment: What environment are you running this in? Node? Browser?

Comment: I update my question,look,please!

Answer (score 0):

base on MDN description about [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) :

> The arguments object is an Array-like object corresponding to the
>   arguments passed to a function.

And :

> This object contains an entry for each argument passed to the
>   function, the first entry's index starting at 0

So with your function **arguments[0]** is refered with variable **a** if it is passed in function, and when you assign arguments[0] , this mean you assign for variable a too .

Hope this helps.

Update from **torazaburo** answer :

> If a is not passed in (as in show()), then arguments[0] does not alias
>   to a, and setting arguments[0] has no effect on a; a remains undefined
>   in this case.

Comment: Right, but you're interpreting the spec incorrectly. Note carefully the part which says **this object contains an entry for each argument passed to the function**. In other words, the `arguments` object will **not** contain an entry just because the parameter is declared, but rather only if it is **passed**, which it is not in the first call to `show()`, and therefore assigning to `arguments[0]` does **not** assign to parameter `a` too.

Answer (score 0):

```
function show(a,b) {
    arguments[0] = 10;
    arguments[1] = 20;
    console.log(a,b);
}
```

If `a` is not passed in (as in `show()`), then `arguments[0]` does **not** alias to `a`, and setting `arguments[0]` has no effect on `a`; `a` remains undefined in this case.